# Is it possible to impart a moment with soundwaves?

Tags: acoustics, torque, rotational-kinematics

How can one adjust the properties of a sound wave to use it to spin an arbitrary object of shape S in a medium comprised of the same material.
My intuition tells me that it would be much more difficult (if not impossible) to do this with spherical objects, so for now we can assume the object is assymetric if that makes things easier.

Comment: By *"an object ... in a medium comprised of the same material"*, do you mean a homogenous medium or that the object is of the same material as the medium. Like a glass duck in a glass block?

Comment: How about something like rotating an aluminium block in a pool of aluminium shavings/sand.